# what is the difference between rdd.repartition() and partition size in sc.parallelize(data, partitions)

Tags: python, apache-spark, rdd

I was going through the documentation of spark. I got a bit confused with rdd.repartition() function and the number of partitions we pass during context initialization in sc.parallelize().

I have 4 cores on my machine, if I sc.parallelize(data, 4) everything works fine, but when I rdd.repartition(4) and apply rdd.mappartitions(fun) sometimes the partitions has no data and my function fails in such cases.

So, just wanted to understand what is the difference between these two ways of partitioning.

Comment: Both can result in empty partitions. You should simply take it into account when you write a function that is intended to be used with `mapPartitions`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By calling `repartition(N)` spark will do a shuffle to change the number of partitions (and will by default result in a HashPartitioner with that number of partitions). When you call `sc.parallelize` with a desired number of partitions it splits your data (more or less) equally up amongst the slices (effectively similar to a range partitioner), you can see this in `ParallelCollectionRDD` inside of the `slice` function.

That being said, it is possible that both of these `sc.parallelize(data, N)` and `rdd.reparitition(N)` (and really almost any form of reading in data) can result in RDDs with empty partitions (its a pretty common source of errors with `mapPartitions` code so I biased the RDD generator in spark-testing-base to create RDDs with empty partitions). A really simple fix for most functions is just checking if you've been passed in an empty iterator and just returning an empty iterator in that case.